# Excel, Stop vba that closes excel when it opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where the client has set this code to run when it opens:

```
Public Sub workbook_open()
    Me.RefreshAll
    Me.Save
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

I need to delete this script but as the macros have been enabled I can't get into the workbook to remove it.  Is there any way to stop the vba code from running or deleting it?

Comment: Hold the left shift key down as you open the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Open another Excel sheet, Disable Macro Rules and then Try opening you Clients sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, if you hold down the shift key when you start Excel to open the workbook.

This disables macros, further hints are [here](http://www.exceltip.com/events-in-vba/prevent-that-an-automacroeventmacro-executes-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html).

Comment: The style of English is somewhat stilted and awkward to understand.